# Use asm in VB.NET

Tags: .net, vb.net, performance, assembly

I wanna call some ASM functions in VB.NET. How can I do it?
It's for performance purpose.

I did not find anything on the web.

Thx

Answer (score 5, accepted):

VB.NET and the CLR in general don't support mixing assembly-code with CIL (it's possible, but let's just assume it isn't) in the same assembly (note that "an assembly" is the name given to a .NET executable and does not refer to "assembly code", it's confusing, I know).

You'll want to do this via interop. You'll want to compile your assembly instructions into their own native Windows DLL file, then export those functions (your assembler/linker will come with instructions on how to do this), then from within VB.NET define a static class ("Module") that has DllImport statements for each exported function from your DLL. Then it's just a matter of calling those functions.

Type conversion ("Marshalling") to native is handled for you by the CLR.

Comment: That depends on what you're wanting to accomplish. The .NET framework already has "native" (non-CIL) implementations of many string operations and other .NET intrinsics. I imagine things in image/video processing and compression/encoding could be sped-up in native (either C/C++ or assembly), but if you're doing that then you might as well write your entire program in C++.

Answer (score 1):

This can be done easily and safely with C#, don't see why it won't work with VB.